# Perl: not an array reference while calculating array size

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I'm trying to untangle some legacy code where an operation is done on $value iff its size is more than x (where x is a hard coded int). This is what it currently looks like:

```
if (scalar(@{$value}) > x) {
    ...
}
```

As with all legacy code, this $value can be almost anything (hash, scalar, array) although it's expected to be an array of different objects. This code currently fails with a "Not an ARRAY reference" around 5% of the time and I'm trying to figure out what's the possible $value that can break it.

I assumed it might fail if the $value is undefined so I even gave it a || [] but to no avail (same error):

```
if (scalar(@{$value || []}) > x) {
    ...
}
```

I'm also trying to figure out why I need the @{}? My understanding is that that evaluates $value in a list context so that scalar can later ensure I get the size. Does that make the code more robust or can I just directly use scalar $value? Does @{} even do what I think it does?

I'm using perl 5.8.

Comment: $value should be a reference to an array. @$value is the array referred to by $value. scalar(@$value) is the number of elements contained in that array. scalar($value) is a just string like "ARRAY(0xce1460)".

Comment: *"I'm using perl 5.8."* Why, oh why? :-(

Comment: @DaveMitchell you, sir, just rewired my brain. Thank you. I had no idea that it'd be a reference. I just assumed perl did some crazy concatenation to get it into a scalar context. Brilliant!

Comment: @DaveCross Two things you don't choose. Your parents and which perl version currently runs your legacy systems :) I appreciate your prayers though hahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions there. I'll answer them separately:

### Question: What is `@{}` doing?

When you write `@{$thing}`, you are **dereferencing** `$thing` into an array. As you have noticed, this only works when `$thing` is an array reference. (Other dereferencing operators are `%{$thing}` for hash references and `${$thing}` for scalar references.)

You *do* need a dereferencing operator there. Consider this:

```
my $arrayref = [ 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie' ];
my $hashref  = { x => 4, y => 5 };
my $string   = "Hello, world";
for my $thing ($arrayref, $hashref, $string) {
    print "thing         --> ", $thing, "\n";
    print "scalar(thing) --> ", scalar($thing), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
thing         --> ARRAY(0x7f3b8054e468)
scalar(thing) --> ARRAY(0x7f3b8054e468)
thing         --> HASH(0x7f3b80560678)
scalar(thing) --> HASH(0x7f3b80560678)
thing         --> Hello, world
scalar(thing) --> Hello, world
```

There's no point in forcing `$thing` to a scalar context. **It's already a scalar!**

### Question: How can I safely dereference a scalar?

If you don't know what kind of reference is contained in `$thing`, you can use [`Ref::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ref::Util) to inspect it:

```
use Ref::Util qw( is_arrayref is_hashref );

for my $thing ($arrayref, $hashref, $string) {
    if (is_arrayref($thing)) {
        print "array: thing         --> ", @{$thing}, "\n";
        print "array: scalar(thing) --> ", scalar(@{$thing}), "\n";
    }
    elsif (is_hashref($thing)) {
        print "hash:  thing         --> ", %{$thing}, "\n";
        print "hash:  scalar(thing) --> ", scalar(%{$thing}), "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "else:  thing         --> ", $thing, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array: thing         --> AliceBobCharlie
array: scalar(thing) --> 3
hash:  thing         --> y5x4
hash:  scalar(thing) --> 2/8
else:  thing         --> Hello, world
```

Observations:

- The arrayref, when dereferenced, becomes a list of its elements. `print` outputs every element with no separators: `AliceBobCharlie`
- The arrayref, when dereferenced and forced into a scalar, becomes the number of elements: `3`
- The hashref, when dereferenced, becomes a list of keys and values. `print` outputs every pair with no separators: `y5x4`
- The hashref, when dereferenced and forced into a scalar, becomes a **string** where the first number is the number of keys and the second number is the number of buckets in the hashtable: `2/8`

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thank you! Reading Dave Mitchell's comment above, it seems you could also do scalar(@$value) without the {}. Does that mean that the {} is just like an anonymous subroutine? Or does it serve some other functionality?

Comment: @AbdoSalem `@$value` and `@{$value}` are exactly the same... it's just syntactic sugar. :) The braces are useful (sometimes needed) when you have to disambiguate access to an arrayref that's nested inside other objects: `@{ $thing->{foo}->{bar} }`

Comment: Brilliant! Really appreciate your detailed answer! :)

Comment: @ysth that's a mini treasure right there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve:

```
if ($value and ref $value eq 'ARRAY' and @$value > x) { ... }
```

Basically you can de-reference to ARRAY only if it's a ARRAY ref. So making sure it's a ARRAY ref is must, so that it won't fail for HASH etc